# jQuery Tools library flashembed and sifr

Tags: jquery, flash, sifr, jquery-tools

I'm using the flashembed method of jQuery Tools library to set up a sifr, but can't seem to get it to work. I've followed their example: http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/flashembed/jquery2.htm
For me all it shows is a flash movie with a white background showing the text: Rendered with sifr3 revision 436. I think I might be missing something very basic here because it shows a flash movie but it doesn't seem to do the siffering of the source text in the H1. I hope anyone has experience in this.

The code I use:

```
<h1 class="sifr">Quote lorem ipsum. Maecenas volutpat urna sit amet ligula dapibus vel ultricies velit interdum.</h1>

$(function() {
    $("h1.sifr").each(function() {
        /*
            place Flash object inside each tag and configure it with
            the replacement text and its style. external CSS has no effect
        */
        flashembed(this, "http://web.admixconnect.nl/www.c2lconsultancy.com/flash/Garamond.swf", {
            txt: $(this).html(),
            css: '* { color: #b4a400; }'
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a single non-sIFR library that does sIFR correctly. Use the official code.

Comment: Because I'm using jQuery more and more often I thought it would be nice to have these other technologies (swfobject, sifr) in jQuery code too... but, since it doesn't have any added benefits in my opinion it was just a side-thought after all! And I'm happy with the original SIFR code.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because you are using different version of sifr.

If I change the sifr swf path to "http://flowplayer.org/swf/itc_century.swf", which is used by the example page you provide, it works fine.

BTW, if you're using sifr, why not using its own js code but go to use jQuery tools?